# How to place a tk button on the top of a frame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a program that has a list of functions on the left. I would like to have the menu start at the top and expand downwards as more buttons are added. However no matter what I do I always get the button in the middle of its widget:

[image]

I am trying to create the button as follows:

```
button = Button (   button_frame, 
                    font = ('Open sans','10','bold'),
                    text='Button',
                    bg='#444444',
                    fg='#cccccc',
                    relief=FLAT,
                    borderwidth=0,
                    highlightthickness = 1,
                    highlightbackground="#222222",
                    command=quit)
button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
```

Comment: The problem is most likely in `button_frame`, which you didn't show - it's shrinking down to fit its contents, so the `sticky` option on `button` has no effect - it's already stuck to all four sides.  The frame itself is where you need `sticky=N`.

Comment: I will try that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution in this case is to use `pack`. Pack is specifically designed to arrange widgets either vertically or horizontally.

```
button.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

If you insist on using `grid`, what you need to do make sure that the grid row *below* the last button has a non-zero weight, and all of the other rows should have a weight of zero. That will cause tkinter to always allocate any extra space below the last button.